# Illegal state exception on finding NavHostFragment from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigationview

I have an activity with layout xml file defined as the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/auth_ui_nav_graph" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now when I try to access the fragment from the context of an activity, I get the Null pointer exception as shown in the following screenshot.

[NullPointerException][1]

```
val navHostFragment =
                supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container) as NavHostFragment
```

Also, the backstack size is empty.

Given that I'm adding the container view to the layout, wouldn't the support fragment manager be able to pick the fragment on its own?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsYYo.png

Comment: Can you please tell me where are you accessing `findFragmentById` ? I want to understand where this function is being called from? is it inside `onCreate` or somewhere else?

Comment: Its called outside the activity and the activity is in the resumed state.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the activity code you've tried? I would like to understand where it's exactly positioned. Right now in your question  i see only 1 line. So I can't determine.